# Predict the next n data points on a time seried with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm looking into examples for time series with Keras and found some good examples for cases where the target is one data point, e.e. in the below code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

## data 
x_train =  np.random.random((100, 10))
x_train = np.reshape(x_train,(100,10,1)) 
y_train =  np.random.random((100, 1))

###training
model = Sequential()

x_shape = 10
y_shape = 1
y_units = 1


model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_shape,y_shape)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=y_units)) #Prediction of the next closing price

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32)

## inference
model.predict(x_train).shape
(100, 1)
```

My question is, which should be the data shapes and NN to predict two values, at first glance what makes sense to me is to have:

```
x_train =  np.random.random((100, 10))
x_train = np.reshape(x_train,(100,10,1))
y_train =  np.random.random((100, 2))
y_train = np.reshape(y_train,(100,2) ) 


model = Sequential()

x_shape = 10
y_shape = 2
y_units = 2


model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_shape,y_shape)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=y_units)) #Prediction of the next closing price

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32)
```

But then I get the error:

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_25: expected shape=(None, None, 2), found shape=(None, 10, 1)

What it has worked is in that same code to change:

```
y_shape = 1
```

then I get the rigth output shape, but I dont understand why the shape of y is set to one if it is a two dimentions array

Answer (score 0):

Input data must be with two units also
`x_train = tf.random.uniform(shape=(100, 10, 2))`

Comment: and what about the y_shape? still got errors if only change that

Comment: No error with only that change and `y_shape = 2`. So your model has two inputs and predict two outputs. The only problem in your code is that the input shape `input_shape=(10, 2)` while train data are `(100,10,1)` but not `(100,10,2)`